# Powerbi calculating sum all other values except selected value using two slicers

Tags: filter, powerbi, selectedvalue, slicers, daxstudio

How to write a powerbi measure for a second slicer which will calculate the sum of all other category except the values selected  in the first slicer?

[image: My data with expected results]